# How do I make the messagebox appear after the conditions are met?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I am trying to create a login screen via Tkinter, and I want the messagebox to display a message when the user has entered the correct username and password, or hasn't entered it correctly.
When I run the program and enter the username and password, the messagebox does not appear.   Is there a way to fix this?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x270")
root.title("staff login")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(background ="black")

label = Label(root, text = "staff log-in") 
frame_heading = Frame(root)
frame_heading.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=25,pady=10)

frame_entry = Frame(root) 
frame_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=25, pady=10)

Label(frame_heading,text ="Staff log-in",
font =('Arial',16))\
                  .grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=5)

Label(frame_entry, text = "Username: ")\
                .grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
label(frame_entry, text = "Password: ")\
                .grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
    
def login():
    label.config (text = "log in")
    username = Entry(frame_entry, width = 15, bg = "white")
    username.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5,pady=5)

    password = Entry(frame_entry, width = 15, bg = "white")
    password.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5,pady=5)

loginbutton = Button(root, text="Login",width=7,
                     command=login)
loginbutton.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=0, pady=5)

def loginbutton():
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()
    if (username == 'admin' and password == 'abcd1234'):
        messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Correct Login')
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Invalid Login')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Which part of your code calls `loginbutton`? It is never called. Also don't name a variable the same as a function and it is `Label` not `label` (on one of your lines).

Comment: I'm guessing you're coming from a different language. In python you don't need the parantheses around `if`.

Comment: You have both a function and a variable named `loginbutton`, and you never call the function which is where the messagebox code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code did not run, so I had to change a few things. You also had it so that you had to press the login button to get the username and password boxes to appear. Here is what I have that I believe is what you are trying to accomplish.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x270")
root.title("staff login")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(background="black")

label = Label(root, text="staff log-in")
frame_heading = Frame(root)
frame_heading.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=25, pady=10)

frame_entry = Frame(root)
frame_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=25, pady=10)

Label(frame_heading, text="Staff log-in",
      font=('Arial', 16)).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=5)

Label(frame_entry, text="Username: ").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
Label(frame_entry, text="Password: ").grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)


# def login(): -- I commented this line because the username and password entries should automatically populate
            #  -- The way you were doing it before these did not populate until after you pressed login
label.config(text="log in")
username = Entry(frame_entry, width=15, bg="white")
username.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

password = Entry(frame_entry, width=15, bg="white")
password.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

# Added the lambda command to the login function you wrote, which was never called anywhere else in the script.
loginbutton = Button(root, text="Login", width=7, command=lambda : loginbutton(username, password))
loginbutton.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=0, pady=5)


def loginbutton(username_entry, password_entry):
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()
    if (username == 'admin' and password == 'abcd1234'):
        messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Correct Login')
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Invalid Login')


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue

There are multiple issues in your code, mainly revolving around giving the wrong variable names. Some of the main issues are:

- In loginbutton you try to access `username_entry` and `password_entry` variable yet when building the widget you did `username = Entry(...)` and `password = Entry(...)`
- the `command` which is going to be invoked when the "Login" button is click is defined as `login` which is the same function that creates the username & password Entry and the Login button

#### Solution

I believe you wanted something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def checkLogin():
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()
    if (username == 'admin' and password == 'abcd1234'):
        messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Correct Login')
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('info', 'Invalid Login')

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x270")
root.title("staff login")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(background ="black")

label = Label(root, text = "staff log-in") 
frame_heading = Frame(root)
frame_heading.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=25,pady=10)

frame_entry = Frame(root) 
frame_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=25, pady=10)

Label(frame_heading,text ="Staff log-in",
font =('Arial',16))\
                  .grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=5)

Label(frame_entry, text = "Username: ")\
                .grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
Label(frame_entry, text = "Password: ")\
                .grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=5)

label.config (text = "log in")
username_entry = Entry(frame_entry, width = 15, bg = "white")
username_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5,pady=5)

password_entry = Entry(frame_entry, width = 15, bg = "white")
password_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5,pady=5)

loginbutton = Button(root, text="Login",width=7,
                     command=checkLogin)
loginbutton.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=0, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

The main point is that when creating the Login button, specify the `command` to `checkLogin` which is the function where you perform any checks after the user clicks the Login button.

Comment: you are indeed correct. Forgot that the widget's variables are being defined in the global scope. Edited answer.